# Some hosts cannot be contacted using their FQDN

Tags: dns

I have a LAN with several hosts connected. I've recently installed a host running `dnsmasq` offering DHCP and DNS-services to the hosts on the LAN. I've noticed since some odd behaviour on the network that I don't understand and may or may not originate from the introduction of the `dnsmasq` host.
I'm at a loss. I have no idea where to look. (I even struggle with coming up with a good title for my question) Please guide me in solving the problem described below.
If extra information is required please let me know and I'll try to add it.

The host running `dnsmasq` (virtual LXC/LXD machine):

```
$ uname -a
Linux dhcpns 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For your basic information, here's the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf |grep -ve '^$' |grep -v '#'
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-poll
server=208.67.220.220
server=8.8.8.8
server=208.67.222.222
server=8.8.4.4
local=/local/
address=/mackeeper.com/0.0.0.0
expand-hosts
domain=local
dhcp-range=10.0.1.100,10.0.1.254,255.255.255.0,72h
dhcp-host=B0:C2:87:79:B0:41,router,   10.0.1.1
# multiple dhcp-host lines for static hosts removed
dhcp-option=option:router,10.0.1.1
dhcp-option=42,10.0.1.220
dhcp-option=15,local
dhcp-option=119,local
dhcp-option=252,"\n"
dhcp-authoritative
log-queries
log-dhcp
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.bak
dhcp-sequential-ip
```

**Here's the problem**

On some hosts (e.g. my MacBook Air; OSX 10.10.5)

```
$ uname -a
Darwin argon.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I can ping all the hosts on the network either by their IP-address, their hostname or their FQDN.

For example, pinging the MySQL server:

```
$ ping -c 1 10.0.1.163
PING 10.0.1.163 (10.0.1.163): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.163: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.245 ms

--- 10.0.1.163 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.245/2.245/2.245/0.000 ms
$ ping -c 1 sql
PING sql.local (10.0.1.163): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.163: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.147 ms

--- sql.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.147/2.147/2.147/0.000 ms
$ ping -c 1 sql.local
PING sql.local (10.0.1.163): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.163: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.246 ms

--- sql.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.246/2.246/2.246/0.000 ms
```

However, on some hosts this doesn't work. E.g.:

```
$ uname -a
Linux rbian 3.18.0-trunk-rpi #1 PREEMPT Debian 3.18.5-1~exp1+rpi19 (2015-08-08) armv6l GNU/Linux

$ ping -c 1 10.0.1.163
PING 10.0.1.163 (10.0.1.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.1.163: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.457 ms

--- 10.0.1.163 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.457/0.457/0.457/0.000 ms
$ ping -c 1 sql
PING sql.local (10.0.1.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sql.local (10.0.1.163): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.393 ms

--- sql.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.393/0.393/0.393/0.000 ms
$ ping -c 1 sql.local
```

**`ping: unknown host sql.local`**

Other hosts respond without a problem:

```
$ ping -c 1 proton.local
PING proton.local (10.0.1.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from proton.local (10.0.1.25): icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=0.619 ms

--- proton.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.619/0.619/0.619/0.000 ms
```

So,some hosts can ping all hosts on the LAN using `hostname.local`, some hosts cannot ping any `hostname.local` and some hosts can ping some of them succesfully. None have a problem pinging just `hostname`.

Please advice me.

**EDIT** : Could this be avahi/netatalk related? In the `dnsmasq-dhcp` logs I see that sometimes/for some hosts the *.local hostname is queried and for others it is not.

**EDIT2** : I've changed two settings:

```
local=/lan/
domain=lan
```

I've also dropped the usage of `*.local` and instead now use `*.lan`. This seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.local is a special-purpose internal DNS zone that Apple OS X uses for Bonjour services.  So yes, you are causing a conflict with Macs natively and Linux running Avahi (Bonjour daemon).

One fix is to run a server-based Multicast DNS responder that they all can use to get a consistent picture of what lives in .local.  The Avahi daemon/server package on any Linux distro can provide this.

You'd be better off overall building on a real DNS domain using a real DNS server and a real DHCP server, particularly if/when this needs to scale.

Comment: By "real DNS domain" do you mean external/commercial or do you mean non-virtual?

Comment: One that is visible and/or resolvable on the public Internet, one that you own.  You can still have a private view (internal) of the domain, but at least you control and have visibility of any internal names that leak out (e.g., internal MTA names that leak in headers of externally-bound email).